# How to align items to right using flexbox?

Tags: css, flexbox, alignment, css-float

I have a structure like so:

```
<footer>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
    </ul>
</footer>
```

With floats, you could `float: left` the `<li>` elements and then `float: right` the `<ul>` to have the links in a row and the entire list at the "end" or the very right of the containing `<footer>`.

How would you accomplish this with flexbox, keeping the container `<footer>` element?

Comment: Why you need flexbox for right align?. You can use float property right?

Comment: Please review and comment on any answer, and let us know if something is unclear or missing. If not, then it would be great if you could accept the answer that helped you the most.

Comment: Since I didn't get any response I deleted my answer

Answer (score 23):

Check the `code` below. You can use `justify-content: flex-end;` so that the flex content will align to the right

```css
footer ul {
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Comment: What browsers support it? I can't find flex-end on caniuse.com

Comment: @Stanislav you check these links https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/justify-content, https://caniuse.com/?search=justify-content

Comment: @Stanislav But if you want to align items to the right with fully support browsers, you can just use `text-align: right` for the parent element and `display: inline-block` for the child elements.

Answer (score 11):

You can use `justify-content: flex-end`

Below is necessary CSS:

```
footer ul {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
```

```css
footer ul {
  justify-content: flex-end;
  list-style: none;
  display: flex;
}
footer ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#">link 1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 2</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">link 3</a></li>
  </ul>
</footer>
```

Answer (score -4):

For this you can use below property

```
ul{
  flex-direction: flex-end;
  display: flex;
}
```

Comment: `flex-direction` property does not have the value `flex-end`. I believed you wanted to use something like `justify-content`.